# Greensock/LoaderMax, Transforming properties of F4V's parent class

Tags: actionscript-3, video, netstream, gsap

I have created a `Player` class which extends `MovieClip` and contains an array of F4V files being loaded via `LoaderMax.parse` ... In my Main Document Class `Main` I want to transform properties of the entire Player class (x, y, alpha, scale, etc.) however the F4V does not see the transformations....It seems I have to reference the content directly from the Main class. For example, if i simply try to set `player.visible=false`, after i've already added video content to the stage, It does not stick, but if I reference `player.video.content.visible=false`, it works...

What I'm really trying to do is fade the player object out before I navigate back to a main navigation screen. I can fade each `video.content` individually but I'd rather just write one tween that effects the whole class. Am I missing something simple or is this larger than I think?

...additionally, these transformations DO work with NetStream driving the f4vs. But looping w netStream is ugly , as we know.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out... I was adding the actual video content to the `stage` so it bypassed all my transformations to `Player`....

Simple!